# Search for string and grab data between brackets proceeding it

Tags: regex, linux, shell, ksh

In ksh/shell, using the below example string, I want to search for the words "Masking View Names" and then extract the data between the brackets (but not including the brackets).

```
Masking View Names
 {
   hostname1
   hostname2
 }
Parent Initiator Groups
 {
   None
 }
```

Comment: It shouldn't be that hard: `Masking View Names\s+{[^}]*}`

Comment: This method includes the brackets and such in the output.

Comment: Just add groups as needed: `(Masking View Names)\s+{([^}]*)}`?